I'm Fetching Error between django and django-filter
My problem is that the django-filter library does not work correctly with the choice fields in django rest framework:
models.py
class Incident(models.Model):
    caller = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Caller',
        verbose_name='caller',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='incidents',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    declarant = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Declarant',
        verbose_name='declarant',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='incidents',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    kind = models.ForeignKey(
        IncidentKind,
        verbose_name='kind',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='incidents',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    duplicate_of = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        verbose_name='duplicate',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='duplicates',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    source = models.CharField(
        'source',
        max_length=255,
        default=consts.IncidentSource.APP,
        choices=consts.IncidentSource.CHOICES,
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        'status',
        max_length=255,
        choices=consts.IncidentStatus.CHOICES,
        default=consts.IncidentStatus.REQUEST_112,
    )

filter
class Incident(django_filters.FilterSet):
    description = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    declarant_phone = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='declarant__phone', lookup_expr='icontains')
    incident_address = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='address__full_address', lookup_expr='icontains')
    source = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=consts.IncidentSource.CHOICES, lookup_expr='icontains')
    status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=consts.IncidentStatus.CHOICES, lookup_expr='icontains')
    service = django_filters.Filter(method='filter_service')
    address_caller = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='caller__address', lookup_expr='icontains')
    victims = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_victims')
    death = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_death')
    dt_create = django_filters.Filter(method='filter_dt_create')
    incident_moment = django_filters.Filter(method='filter_incident_moment')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Incident
        fields = [
            'is_needs_reaction',
            'is_social_significant',
            'is_risk_emergency',
            'description',
            'declarant_phone',
            'status',
            'source',
            'operator',
            'incident_address',
            'kind',
            'service',
            'address_caller',
            'victims',
            'death',
            'dt_create',
        ]

Source and status choices field.
I got Error
super()._set_choices(value)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_set_choices'


If I use CharFilter, then the filtering works, but not quite as it should
source = django_filters.CharFilter(choices=consts.IncidentSource.CHOICES, lookup_expr='icontains')
    status = django_filters.CharFilter(choices=consts.IncidentStatus.CHOICES, lookup_expr='icontains')

My traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/core/tests/test_incident.py", line 60, in test_update
    response = self.client.put(self.detail_url)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 304, in put
    response = super().put(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 214, in put
    return self.generic('PUT', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 234, in generic
    return super().generic(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 617, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 286, in request
    return super().request(**kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 238, in request
    request = super().request(**kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 1013, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 743, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 124, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 65, in update
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 87, in get_object
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 154, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 94, in filter_queryset
    if not filterset.is_valid() and self.raise_exception:
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 212, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and self.form.is_valid()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/filterset.py", line 24, in form
    form = super().form
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 264, in form
    Form = self.get_form_class()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 254, in get_form_class
    fields = OrderedDict([
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 255, in <listcomp>
    (name, filter_.field)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filters.py", line 137, in field
    self._field = self.field_class(label=self.label, **field_kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/fields.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/fields.py", line 262, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 880, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/fields.py", line 268, in _set_choices


I also just tried passing the source and status fields to the fields field, it didn't help either.
He asked GPT questions, he says that one of the possible problems may be a bug in the library itself, so he decided to ask another question here, in case someone had a similar situation

Remove the lookup_expr when using a choice field. It is by default using the exact lookup expresion since it is a choice field.
An example of a working filter from my Django application looks like this:
DOMAIN_CHOICES = (
    ('Educations', 'Educations'),
    ('Certificates', 'Certificates'),
    ('Qualifications', 'Qualifications'),
)

class HistoryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    domain = filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=DOMAIN_CHOICES, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeHistory
        fields = ['domain']


OK, I made an exact example like yours:
status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=consts.IncidentStatus.CHOICES, required=True)<br/>
Example consts:
    CHOICES = (<br/>
        (REQUEST_112, REQUEST_112_RUS),<br/>
        (VIEWING, VIEWING_RUS),<br/>
        (CONNECTION, CONNECTION_RUS),<br/>
        (REACTION, REACTION_RUS),<br/>
        (ACCEPTED, ACCEPTED_RUS),<br/>
        (COMPLETED, COMPLETED_RUS),<br/>
        <br>(REJECTION, REJECTION_RUS),<br/>
    )```
My mistake remains.

sorry, this is the first question on the stack, I still don't know how to format blocks in the code in the comments

I had the same error. After investigating the code, I noticed that the ._set_choices method used to render the choices was not found. I was using django-filter==22.1. I updated to the latest version, django-filter==24.3, and it worked for me.
